# What is the complexity of computation of zero point by Rieman zeta function?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, comp-number-theory

What is the complexity of computation  of zero point by  Rieman zeta function?
That is, given s, whether ζ(s)=0? Is it in P? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: It may be me but I fail to clearly understand your question. Before talking about complexity, it should be clear what the input is. Do you want to check, given $s$, whether $\zeta(s)=0$? Do you want to enumerate them? Or something else?

Comment: @holf given s, whether ζ(s)=0? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: How is $s$ given? Potential zeroes of $\zeta$ are complex numbers, not finite objects.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek any good finite represent is ok, for instance, a program that outputs the number. Obviously, the program is finite that is with finite length. Thank you Emil, We usually meet on my question.